# Ionic cordova run android and update file from folder

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like to be able to upload/update files from my local machine using real device android.

I've wrote this command line :

```
ionic cordova run android
```

from my ionic project folder.

I can see my app on the real device but when i update a file from the project folder, i can't see the result in the real device.

If i want to see the change i have to re-run android.

Is there a way without android studio to be able to see the changes after editing a file in the ionic project'folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build every time on mobile,  you can run your application on browser if you want to see the results after editings.

Comment: I think i found a usefull information here https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android

Comment: So did you try this command : `ionic run android --device -l` ?

Comment: Actually i try to reflect my folder and files with cordova to the real device

Comment: File like a txt file or json ?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i had to run this command and the local machine folder reflect the real device app :

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload -cs
```